# How to return the existing (current) route from go_router?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I'm using [`go_router_builder`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router_builder) to build routes. Here's one:

```dart
class FooRoute extends GoRouteData {
  final bool condition;
  FooRoute(this.condition);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    return condition ? FooScreen() : null; // I wish this was possible!
  }
}
```

I want to keep the existing route (screen) if the `condition` is false. How can I do that?

```dart
void func() {
  FooRoute(true); // Navigates to the `FooScreen`. All good.
  FooRoute(false); // This should do nothing. 
}
```

---

**Note:**

I want to keep my logic in the `FooRoute` widget.

Comment: You can use the redirect method in `GoRouter` class

Comment: @Delwinn I am new to `go_router`, I'd appreciate if you can write it in answer.

Comment: why dont you check out this video? https://youtu.be/5nQQv_nbFqY?t=905

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the current route, you can do so using `GoRouter.of(context).location` getter method.

For example:

```dart
final currentLocation = GoRouter.of(context).location;
print(currentLocation) // "/HomePage/Notifications"

// and here you can do your conditions based on the current location
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? I don't want to get the current route.

Comment: I am sorry but that is what I understand from the question title
`How to return the existing (current) route from go_router?`

Comment: That's fine. (1) The title says `How to return ...`, not `How to get ...` (2) StackOverflow also allows users to provide additional information in the body of the post in case the title isn't clear enough. So, spending about 10-15 seconds to read through the body might have given you a better understanding of the question, potentially saving you a few minutes in writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
final currentRoute = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.name!;
```